# create regular CUDA kernels on thrust vector types

Tags: cuda, thrust

i've a simple question , if for example i would like to use a cuda kernel i wrote on a thrust vector , must i cast my device_vector into a regular pointer type? or is there another way?

oh and another thing , regarding the device_vector constructur ,
if i have a pointer allocated on the GPU , is there a quick device_vector that accepts that pointer or am i supposed to tranfer everything first to the CPU and only then declare my device_vector with the appropriate arguments(CPU allocated variables) ?

Thanks , igal !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i would like to use a cuda kernel i wrote on a thrust vector , must i cast my device_vector into a regular pointer type?

You have 2 options:

1. You can use functors and general algorithms. Details [in manual](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/downloads/detail?name=An%20Introduction%20To%20Thrust.pdf) (pp
   18-22). I can also advice to look close to `zip_iterator`'s
2. If you have a non standard algorithm or you're already have a
   kernel, then it will be more simple to cast vector to `raw_pointer` ([manual](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/downloads/detail?name=An%20Introduction%20To%20Thrust.pdf) p. 11)

> if i have a pointer allocated on the GPU , is there a quick device_vector that accepts that pointer

To use standart algorithms you can wrap pointer to class device_ptr. Then you can use object same as device_vector.

```
int N = 10;
// raw pointer to device memory
int * raw_ptr;
cudaMalloc((void **) &raw_ptr, N * sizeof(int));
// wrap raw pointer with a device_ptr
thrust::device_ptr<int> dev_ptr(raw_ptr); // use device_ptr in thrust algorithms
thrust::fill(dev_ptr, dev_ptr + N, (int) 0); // access device memory through device_ptr
dev_ptr[0] = 1;
// free memory
cudaFree(raw_ptr);
```

Code from [manual](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/downloads/detail?name=An%20Introduction%20To%20Thrust.pdf) p. 12.